# Using jQuery to load icon based on <label> contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website where the content is dynamically loaded from a database. The  contents varies for each label.

One may be generated as General:, whilst another may be generated as TV:. 
My question is, is there any way that jQuery could (based on the HTML output for the label) replace the NAME: with a font awesome icon?

So for example:

```
<label>TV:</label>
```

Would become:

```
<i class="fa fa-film fa-2x"></i>
```

Comment: Will there be anything else in that label besides the text? And yeah it can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```js
var icons = {
    'tv:': 'film',
    'edit:': 'edit'
};

$('label').replaceWith(function () {
    var text = $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase(),
        icon = icons[text];
    return icon ? '<i class="fa fa-' + icon + ' fa-2x"></i>' : undefined;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<label>TV:</label>
<label>TsV:</label>
<label>EDIT:</label>
```

Comment: This works really nice, but I think he meant just the text string not the whole label.

Comment: @Spokey OP said the `label` will `Would become:` so I assumed OP wants it to be replaced

Comment: Thanks very much, this works really well and exactly what I was after! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You could use the :contains selector http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
$("label:contains('TV')").html('<i class="fa fa-film fa-2x"></i>');
```

Comment: Interesting and laconic solution! But if I have, for example, label with "red-tv" it will be replaced with fa-film too. But I don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("label:contains('TV')").html('<i class="YOUR CLASS"></i>');
```

or if you could add class or id in that label you could change it easily like

```
 $("#ID").html('<i class="YOUR CLASS"></i>');

 $(".CLASS").html('<i class="YOUR CLASS"></i>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace them with JQuery for example

```
var icons = {
    "TV:" : "film"
};

var $labels = $('label');
$labels.each(function(index){
    var icon = icons[$(this).text()];
    $(this).replaceWith($("<i>").addClass('fa').addClass('fa-' + icon).addClass('fa-2x'));
});
```

And see Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m19hjnoa/

Answer (score 1):

You could take different aproaches on that.

My personal favorite would be to just send the right label from the server.

otherwise you could run this jQuery Script: http://jsfiddle.net/ehdgL6so/

```
// try to select as less elements as possible for speed
// for example if they are in a div with class foo try jQuery('div.foo label') instead
var labels = jQuery('label');

// loop throu all labels
labels.each(function() {
    // get single label element
    var label = jQuery(this);
    // get the content (for example "TV:"
    var labelContent = label.text();

    // replace if the label matches
    switch(labelContent) {
        case 'TV:':
            // if the label contains "TV:" replace the <label> with the <i> element
            label.replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-film fa-2x"></i>');
            break;
        case 'Foo':
            // if the label contains "Foo" replace foo with the <i> element
            label.html('<i class="fa fa-film fa-2x"></i>');
            break;
    } 
});
```

Edit:
Or as @cforcloud suggests a short Form like

```
// note: .html does just replace the string "TV:" but leaves the label element in the DOM, while replaceWith is the way to replace an element
// http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/
jQuery("label:contains('TV:')").replaceWith('<i class="fa fa-film fa-2x"></i>');
```